# href attribute in webview IOS with jQuery-Mobile

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, uiwebview, safari

A simple code ...

This code is inside html head tag. The includes of jquery-mobile, and jQuery are correct.

```
$(document).ready(function() {           
    $("a").click(function () {       
       var t = $(this).attr('href');
    });
});
```

but not works in webview IOS but in Chrome works fine.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? it doesn't do anything... put  `alert('foo)` inside of the event...

Answer (score 1):

try [vclick](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html) event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").vclick(function (){        
       var t = $(this).attr('href');
    });
});
```

Comment: I found the solution!

    $(document).ready(function() 
     {
      //When the file is executed from Native...
      $("a").touchstart(function (){        
         var t = $(this).attr('href');
         alert(t);
      });
                //else if is executed from Web Browser....
      $("a").click(function (){        
         var t = $(this).attr('href');
         alert(t);
      });
     });

This works fine!!!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't really checked, but `click` events in iOS are handled (and behave for that matter) a bit differently than desktop counterparts.

Have you [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585689/ios-not-recognising-click-events)?