# Cannot target clicked element in iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css

I have tried and failed for over a week now to figure out why my iOS devices won't target a click on a specific element.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uXPkH/4/)

In this JSFiddle you can try to click on 1. Background, then when you click on one of the colored buttons it works like a charm, unless you use an iOS device. Why is that? I can'f figure it out.

It is this .colors li that is not going to be trigged in iOS devices for some reason.

```
$('.colors li').click(function(){
    alert('yo');
});
```

Here are the actual code that doesn't even get triggered

```
$(document).on('click', '.bg ul.colors li', function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.case_background').css({ 'background': $(this).css('background') });

    caseObject.background = $(this).css('background');
});
```

Just found out that even if I say, nothing is getting logged:

```
$(document).on('click', function(){ console.log('click') });
```

Comment: Could you try: `$('.colors li').attr('onclick','$.noop()').click(function(){
    alert('yo');
});` or maybe just set `onclick` attribute as empty string

Comment: maybe a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095868/jquery-click-not-working-in-ios or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585689/ios-not-recognising-click-events or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795944/jquery-click-events-not-working-in-ios ?

Comment: @A.Wolff sorry, but no luck there either. It is not even getting triggered.

Answer (score 1):

IOS have touch events.. not click use:

```
$('.colors li').bind("click touchstart", function(){
    alert('yo');
});
```

Comment: It works well with click at the "Layout"-tab in my example. Tried it out with this now as well but no luck. Thanks for your reply tho :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a well known problem with IOS devices, triggering the hover event when you click it once. So Hardy is right.

But to go further into why your "Layout"-tab works fine and your "Background"-tab isn't. It could be because you use LI in the "background"-tab and you use a Button element in the "Layout"-tab.

You could check this question for a fix to this problem: [iOS automatic hover fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507964/ios-automatic-hover-fix)

Comment: No, there is a ul.layouts there as well, not filled out in the fiddle, sorry for that.

Comment: Btw, I can click on the menu in the phone as well, and that is also a list.